# Can one configure per-client non-closing SSH session on server side?

Tags: ssh, sshd

On SSH client side one can configure per-server keepalives so that connection to a single server is kept up:

```
Host example
    Hostname example.com
    ServerAliveInterval 240
```

On server side one can set the client timeout:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

I've not found the syntax for configuring this on the server on per-client basis. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sshd_config file supports matching rules to segregate configurations to specific machines or groups of machines.

The default config file (on most distros) has a line

```
Host *
```

indicating that the following lines are for all hosts...

You can add more matches and configurations at the end of the file or on some distros, in `ssh_config.d/`.

Comment: ARGH! I really should have my caffeine levels balanced first... I misinterpreted `ClientAliveInterval` earlier :-D Thanks.

Comment: Oddly, I can't find any mention of the `Host` keyword match in the sshd_config man page.  Instead it shows `Match`

Comment: I thought I just missed it ref. caffeine levels. It's not in O'Reilly's [SSH definitive guide](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/appb_03.htm) either. You know it to work from experience?

Comment: It's in the default config file, and not commented out and it doesn't give a parse error, so...

Comment: I'm thinking that "Match" replaces "Host" and they removed host from the man page but didn't depreciate it for use in the config file.  I don't have a man page old enough to prove this.

Comment: I don't have it either in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config' or `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config`, only `HostKey` and `HostbasedAuthentication`; and `Match` here is user-specific, not IP- or session-specific. OpenSSH 8.4p1.

Comment: There's like 6 keywords that can be used with Match including Host.

Comment: I have to look deeper into it and play around. It's nothing urgent, rather just curiosity. as I didn't find this anywhere either, and not having that possibility doesn't really fit the way things usually work :-)